# android HAL, how the application grant permission to access the sensor?

Tags: android

I'm looking into android HAL and try to understand how the apps grant permission to access the sensor or hardware. The case is, I do not root my device(I can, but I won't), so if you want to tell me root the device or modify init.rc file, please save your time, thanks.

I did some tests.

> 1. I tried to directly get access to some sensors or hardwares in JAVA code, like new FileOutputStream("/dev/XXX"), failed.
> 2. I tried to use JNI, like, fd = open("/dev/XXX", O_RDWR, 0), failed.
>
> I guess both of them above are permission denied.
>
> 3. I used the sample named "native-activity" under NDK directory. It's a pure C code. And finally get the value from the sensors.

So I don't know in the case 3, how and when this "native-activity" app grant the permission, which is able to get the value from sensors.

I may misunderstand something. Correct me if you think there is something wrong. Thanks